# Failing openssl_public_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, x509certificate, public-key-encryption, php-openssl

When I'm encrypting a variable where I put some text in it, it's working, but if I'm using a variable where I'm assigning to the $output this:

```
$data1 = new DOMDocument("1.0", "utf-8");
//creating the xml document
...
//after creating the document
$output = $data1->saveXML();
```

where $data1 is an xml object. After that I'm using a public certificate to extract the public key, for encrypting the string $output:

```
$pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('./certificate.cer'));
$keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);
$key = $keyData['key'];
```

After I have the public key in the variable $key, I want to encrypt the $output with the public key $key, and I'm using the following code to handle possible error:

```
$crypted='';
if (($blnResult = openssl_public_encrypt($output, $crypted, $key)) === false) {
    throw new \Exception("error: openssl_public_encrypt() failed!");
}

echo base64_encode($crypted);
```

And it gives me the `error: openssl_public_encrypt() failed!`. Notice that if I'm assigning to `$output='foo'`, it's working, so I don't understand why it isn't working if I'm assigning to `$output the data->saveXML();`? It is a 270 characters long string. It "should" work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openssl\_public\_encrypt not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46378455/openssl-public-encrypt-not-working)

Comment: What’s the key size? A 2048 bit key can encrypt up to 245 bytes.

Comment: I guess it's a 2048 bit key. I saw that I can't give more than 117 characters. So what can I do to increase the size?

Comment: Stop using RSA to encrypt directly. `openssl_seal()` is safer. Switching to libsodium and using `sodium_crypto_box_seal()` is even better.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My problem was that either the public key I used was very short or the data I was trying to encrypt was very long. So, you have 2 options:
- You may reduce the amount of data you are trying to encrypt or,
- You may use a public key that allows you to encrypt more data (a bigger public key)

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)

Comment: This saved me so much time! I also had a similar problem where some requests we were sending to a 3rd party were working while others were failing. After reading this, we requested another key which worked. Thanks!